# Is there a TF function similar to SciPy rank data

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy

#### Question:

SciPy has a [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.rankdata.html), rankdata which returns the rank of each index of a matrix.

#### Example

```py
    Values          Ranked
-------------   ------------
[0, 4, 2, 6]     [0, 2, 1, 3]
[7, 5, 1, 0] --> [3, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 8, 1, 0]     [1, 3, 1, 0]
```

Is there a way to do this with Tensorflow? I need to GPU accelerate the rank data function on a 100 x 100 x 20,000 matrix.

#### Language

I'd like to use Tensorflow because it will let me use either python or C++.

Is there a different library which will let me GPU accelerate this, like Thrust or cuBLAS, that would work?

Answer (score 0):

How about [argsort](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argsort)? It wouldnt have the same handling for ties, though.

Comment: I've been using argsort as a stand in for now, but like you mentioned, it doesn't handle ties the same way which I actually do need. Do you know any way to augment the way argsort handles ties?